Current-to-voltage converter not reaching expected Output
I have this circuit:
(Current-to-voltage converter, second circuit on this page)
The OpAmp is lm358A (datasheet)
The Supply voltage of the OpAmp is +18V and -12V
For Rf is used 500 Ohm
Iin = 20mA
Vout only reaches -9.6V (instead of the expected -10V)
The span from 0mA up to 19.5mA works like i intended according to Vout = Rf * Iin
If i change the supply voltage of the negative voltage from -12V to -13V the output behaves as expected. I inspected the datasheet multiple times for the max output current and the capability to reach that expected -10V and couldn't find an answer for that behavior.
Why doesn't the OpAmp reach the desired -10V at 20mA Input current with a supply voltage of +18 / -12V ?

Do you need to convert only positive currents (flowing "into" the circuit to make the output voltage negative), or also negative currents?

I just need to convert positive currents with the circuit

According to the OpAmp's datasheet, it is only rated to sink up to 10mA. This is specified on page 7, section "output", parameter "Io". You're demanding more from the OpAmp than TI guarantees it can handle.
Figure 6-12 (page 17, bottom right) shows the sinking behavior over temperature of a typical LM358A. As you can see, 20mA is just on the edge of bringing the output stage to its knees. Depending on the ambient temperature and chip-to-chip variations, the OpAmp may or may not be able to sink 20mA, and even if it can, it might need significant voltage headroom to do so.
To fix this, add an external buffer stage:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
With the buffer, the circuit demands less than 1mA sinking current from the LM358, which it is guaranteed to handle with at most 1V of headroom. Add in the 700mV or so from the PNP follower transistor, and you get a total of 1.7V, leaving you with 300mV to spare out of the total 2V headroom you have. Not much, but it'll work.
If you need to only convert positive input currents, you can omit the NPN transistor (Q1) from the circuit.
